# Can I use branch for different projects in single repo?

Tags: git, git-branch

I have some projects with independent code, but similiar purpose. Can I create a giant git repo and create different branch to hold different projects?
For example I want to create a repo named database, and create different branches to hold source code of MySQL, PostGres and ClickHouse. Does it make sense?

Comment: You can. But the user experience might be bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some git operations will be slower due to the size of such a repository, but it is perfectly fine.

Git even comes with a lot of built-in support for creating and working with repositories like this:

- `git switch --orphan` for creating new orphan branches
- `get merge --allow-unrelated-histories` for merging between branches with different roots
- `get worktree` for checking out branches in a separate folder
- `git submodule` easily handles submodules that point into the same repository